# How to select multiple non adjecent methods in Nautilus? (Pharo Smalltalk Windows)

Tags: windows, pharo

As a windows user I'd expect to use ctrl+{left mousebutton click} but this gives me the context menu instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you hit a bug we currently have :(

https://pharo.fogbugz.com/f/cases/15981

(but you will need to have an account to see it...)

Comment: just registered to pharo.fogbugz.com and subscribed to the case.
Thanks for the fast answer.